# How can I bypass my login script?

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

I've created a below script, which is intentionally not secure, in order to learn a bit more about cyber security.

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['userSession']) {
    header("location: home.php");
}


if($_POST) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myUsername", "myPassword", "myDatabase");
    if(!$con) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' && password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $numResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($numResults == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['id'];
        header("location: home.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error Logging In";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

As you can see, I have not escaped the user input and the password has not been hashed.
Therefore, I am presuming that this should be an easily hackable login. However, I have attempted to use the below input in both of the username and password fields, but always get the output "Error Logging In".

```
password' OR '1' = '1'";
```

How can I try to bypass/hack my login script?

Comment: check link for sql injection: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Get rid of the last `'` so your password looks like so: `foo' or '1' = '1`

Answer (score 2):

If we use sql statement directly to fetch username and password field then it can be bypass with `' OR '1' = '1` pattern, because when you put `' OR '1' = '1` in username and password field that values carry forward to sql statement and in that statement `' or '1' = '1` is **true** for all the cases and that's a reason login can bypass.